# <!-- ngInclude: undefined -->

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, coffeescript

Can you help me about this?

```
This is my ng-include path "http://localhost:8080/coffeeprojects/calc.html"
```

I tried that path and it's working but 
I checked some of the answers and some said check the path, and after I organize the files and make a better path for it, the error still shows up.

Well I'm using append of jQuery to generate this
    http://localhost:8080/coffeeprojects/calc.html'">
that is the not working.

But when I tried to put it on the page it loads.

Sources:

**Coffeescript**

**app.coffee**

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $("#calc").hide()
  link =  ->
  $('.col-md-6 a').click ->
    $('.col-xs-4').hide()
    $('#greet').hide()

    project = $(@).attr("href")
    $(project).show()

    html = $(@).data "projects"
    $(@).append("<ng-include src=\"'#{html}'\" >
                </ng-include>").after()
```

Comment: You have to compile the dynamically generated html, using `$compile` service.

Comment: why are you using jQuery to inject angular code?

Comment: I thing u need to use the relative path

Comment: @charlietfl im trying to load a html page without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: @Chandermani how can i compile in windows? sorry i dont know how to do it

Comment: right and in order for angular to recognize a newly added directive you have to use angular `$compile` , read the docs. If you got rid of trying to do this using jQuery in the first place it would be simpler

Answer (score -1):

You can have the ng-include in your html and load the src attribute with a scope property, something like:

```
<ng-include src="{{myScopePropertyWithPath}}"></ng-include>
```

That would allow you to get rid of jquery code and keep everything whithin the realms of angularjs :)